# Create histogram with frame in plot nine

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I would like to create a histogram with a frame, where not all bars have a frame, but over the collected bars.

I first had the idea to create a geom_histo with color, and then to create a geom_histo with the fill filled, but it cuts off the "frame" weirdly for me....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.